# Assign the value to different field ID?

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have a form with a unique identifier field that the user needs to enter, when passing this value it needs to appear in different field id. so for instance. the field that user enters the unique code in is called "unique" and the copy needs to be in "message", how can i achieve that?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="pins" id="pinLabel"><span style="color:#f22300">*</span>&nbsp;Unique Code:</label>
                        <input data-mini="true" name="pins_r" id="pins" placeholder="9 alphanumeric characters"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" id="msg" name="msg" value=pins>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Ankur, Thanks for your reply, i just updated the post, i want msg to have the same value as pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this with JavaScript.

Method 1)

Have an onchange event on the unique field such that whenever the value is changed, change it in a hidden field called message.

```
<input type="text" id="unique" name="unique" onchange="setMessage(this);">
<input type="hidden" id="message" name="message">

function setMessage(field) {
    document.getElementById('message').value = field.value;
}
```

Method 2)

Use ajax to post the form instead, that way you can build the fields yourself.

ie. post message= document.getElementById('unique').value

Both the above are greatly improved if you use JQuery or another JS helper framework.

Comment: Hi imothee, thanks for your reply, i tried your second method, before i submit the form, didn't work out. the message was not recognised.

Comment: Hi Lyad - how are you posting the form? The second method will only work using JQuery or another lib to do an Ajax post.

If you are using Jquery and doing $(form).submit(function($.post({ ... }))); it should work. However, this only works if you create the post values manually. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Replace above for whatever js framework you use to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your values to be set in the label at the same time, it is entered.

You can do some thing like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#pins').keypress(function() {
        setTextValueForPins(this);
    });
});

function setTextValueForPins(textPin)
{
$('#pinLabel').text($('#textPin').val());
}
```

If you want the value to be set after the user have entered the value, you can use the change event.

PS: Not tested the code , let me know if you face any Issues.